# Efficient algorithm for LCA (Lowest Common Ancestor) if the tree is updated with 1-node deletions and insertions

Tags: algorithm, tree, theory

I am looking for efficient algorithm to perform LCA in a generic tree. The important detail is that after every LCA query, the tree is updated by 1 node mutation (i.e. the node is deleted from its previous position and inserted at a new one).

Thanks for ideas/references.

Comment: How large of a tree are we talking about? Dynamic trees will give you O(log n) for all of these operations, but the big-O constant is large.

Comment: Is the moving node always a leaf?  If not, then what do you do with its children?

Comment: The tree is 10^4-10^6 nodes, unbalanced, not a binary or any other way structured.
Dynamic trees is an interesting idea at the first glance but I need to investigate it deeper.

Comment: The moving node is not necessary a leaf node.
The bigger problem is optimization of the tree structure (nothing related to balancing, it's more like patterns) so nothing special is done for leaves.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Can you give a reference for the Dynamic trees that you mention? I have a similar question and O(log n) would be worth looking at

Comment: @tarulen this paper: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf. I implemented it and a bunch of other stuff: https://www.davideisenstat.com/dtree/